# Existence of limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ of a continous bounded function with certain condition

Tags: real-analysis

I have this problem: Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a continuous bounded function with the following property: for every $t \geq 0$,
$$\lim_{s \to \infty}|f(s) - f(t+s)| = 0$$
I would like to prove that $\lim_{s \to \infty}f(s)$ exists.

I can prove that this function is uniformly continuous but it does not help much. Actually, I have a kind of uniform continuity when $s$ is big enough. I tried Cauchy's characterization but I cannot get something significant. Any hint people? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I think then $sin(logx)$ works instead. (with an offset so it's in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$)

Comment: Just to clarify: when Zoe says $\sin(\log(x))\ $ "works", (I believe) she means it is a counter-example. In other words, it is an example such that, for every $t \geq 0$,
$\lim_{s \to \infty}|f(s) - f(t+s)| = 0\ $ but $\lim_{s \to \infty}f(s)$ does not exist.

Comment: Since OP wants a positive function we could add $2$ to Zoe Allen's example.

Comment: Zoe's right. It disproves my claim. Thanks!